# How to update the table in the MasterViewController

Tags: xcode, ipad

I am using a Master-Detail template.
I have a segmented control in the detail view and I have set the MasterViewController as the delegate.
This enables me to give the user choices.
I know the segmented control is working and passing the choices to the MVC.

I want each choice to trigger a new set of data which can then be loaded into the table view in the MasterViewController.
My problem is that I cannot then find a way to update the data in the table view.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? If I understood your question, then I would use `[tableView reloadData]` on `viewWillAppear` of `MasterViewController`every time

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code from both header and implementation files that refers to _tableChoiceToDisplay and chooseTopic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an instance variable declared in `MasterViewController` to be updated while `UISegmentedControl` changes. Based on that, When you come back to the `MasterViewController`; use its `viewWillAppear` to `[tableView reloadData]`

Tell me if I am getting your question *wrong*.

EDIT:

Take an `integer` name it `segmentIndex`; update as and when Segment gets changed. Based on the value of `segmentIndex` load the `dataSource` needed to be displayed on `UITableView` of your `MasterViewController`

EDIT 2:

When `UISegmentedControl`'s value changes, put `mvc.segmentIndex = (currentValueOfYourSegmentedControl)`;
Then in `MasterViewController`'s `viewWillAppear`

```
switch (self.segmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
           // Set Datasource for First Choice.
           break;
    case 0:
           // Set Datasource for Second Choice.
           break;
    case 0:
           // Set Datasource for Third Choice.... and so on...
           break;
    default:
           // Default Behavior
           break;
}
```

Hope You Get My Point.

Comment: Looks promising, Matt, but instance variable of what? I did try using [tableView reloadData] but it didn't work.

Comment: I have already used this code in my DVC:              MasterViewController *mvc= [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
    self.delegate=mvc;

Comment: I am doing something similar.

In DVC I have a function chooseTopic which calls a function in the MVC called changeTopicTo.
My segmented control has 3 sections, Micro, Macro and International.
ChooseTopic sends the info from the segmented control to the the changeTopicTo function.

ChangeTopicTo says:

    (NSString *)changeTopicTo: (NSString *)topic
{
_tableChoiceToDisplay=topic;
return _tableChoiceToDisplay;
}

NSLog tells me that _tableChoiceToDisplay is working because it reads “Micro”, “Macro”, etc.

But if I then try NSLog for _tableChoiceToDisplay in viewDidAppear it gives me null.

Comment: I could not format the above. Basically, I am getting the information to the MVC but cannot access it from viewWillAppear. The variable I am changing can be accessed from the function in MVC. It is _tableChoiceToDisplay and is a string. But when I use NSLog in viewWillAppear it says _tableChoiceToDisplay is null.

Comment: Can you post more code? I wanna check each and every statements containing and manipulating `_tableChoiceToDisplay`

Comment: I am only allowed a certain number of lines of code.It won't fit in this box. But segmentIndex is just returning 0 in MVC.

Comment: In DVC the code is  mvc.segmentIndex = self.topicsChoiceSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
and it returns correct index number. In MVC self.segmentIndex returns 0 in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your contribution put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would use notifications instead of delegates. i.e Detect the segmentedControl value change using valueChanged inside the detailViewController and then post an NSNotification from your detailViewcontroller which your masterViewController receives.

Easiest way is:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"segmentOneChosen" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Have you masterViewController register for this notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(segmentOneChosen) name:@"segmentOneChosen" object:nil];
```

It would be better still to pass the chosen value along with the notification so you don't need a separate notification for each segment.

!! untested code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"segmentChosen", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.topicsChoiceSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex], nil];
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"segmentChosen" object:nil userInfo:dict];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(segmentChosen:) name:@"segmentChosen" object:nil];

-(void) segmentChosen:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSNumber *segmentChosenNum = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"segmentChosen"];
}
```

I know this doesn't answer your question per se, but it does provide an alternative solution to the problem you are trying to overcome.